# One-line way to remove last n characters from string

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, command-line-interface

I have a bunch of files in the format `photo.jpg.png` in a folder, and for every photo in this folder, I want to replace the `.jpg.png` with `.png`. How can I do this from Terminal?

I have a basic Python and bash background, so I know I'd want to do something like this:

```
 $ for i in *.png; do mv $i $i[:-8]; done
 $ for i in *; do mv $i $i.png; done
```

But what would I replace the Pythonic `[:-8]` with in order to remove the last 8 characters of each filename?

**EDIT** I now realize that a substring that counts from the end of the string would be superior. Is there a way to do this as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use pattern expansion:

```
for f in *.jpg.png; do mv -v "$f" "${f/.jpg.png/.png}"; done
```

Though you might still have problems with a filename like `foo.jpg.png.gif`.

If you really want to strip the last 7 or 8 characters, you can use a substring expansion:

```
for f in *.jpg.png; do mv -v "$f" "${f:0:-7}png"; done
```

Note that use of negative numbers in substring length requires bash version 4 or higher.

Comment: It's a bash [_parameter expansion_](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), sed like

Comment: The `/` inside the curly braces denotes **pattern substitution**, a type of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). Per the man page: `${parameter/pattern/string}`, where the pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion, and *parameter* is expanded and the longest match of *pattern* against its value is replaced with *string*. There's more, you should probably check out the man page, among [other things](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string). :)

Comment: For the (admittedly very unlikely) case of a filename containing `.jpg.png` somewhere other than the end, you could anchor the pattern to be replaced at the end with `"${f/%.jpg.png/.png}"`.

Comment: @BenjaminW., you could indeed. Excellent suggestion. And in fact, you could also make this POSIX compliant easily enough with `"${f%jpg.png}png"`, as long as you're implicitly validating the input by matching only compatible files with the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

With Perl's standalone `rename` command:

```
rename -n 's/jpg\.png$/png/' *.jpg.png
```

or

```
rename -n 's/.......$/png/' *.jpg.png
```

Output:

```
rename(photo.jpg.png, photo.jpg)
```

If everything looks okay, remove `-n'.

Comment: `rename` is written in Perl, but it's not *part* of Perl; it may or may not be installed on any given system.

Comment: [perl's rename standalone](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

Answer (score 1):

`rename` is designed for this kinda thing;

```
$ rename .jpg.png .png *.jpg.png
```

For MacOS, I realized that `rename` may not be available by default, you can install it using `brew`.

```
$ brew install rename
```

and then use `-s` option for `rename`;

```
$ rename -s .jpg.png .png *.jpg.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the last 8 characters using perl's rename :

```
$ rename -n 's/.{8}$//' *.png
```

(remove -n switch when your tests are OK)
or with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
for i in *.png; do
    echo mv "$i" "${i:0:-8}"
done
```

(remove `echo` when your tests are OK)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

and not containing:

```
ELF
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://web.archive.org/web/20130625192518/https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: added bash way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
$ v=test.jpg.png
$ echo ${v:0:-8}
test
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for file in *.jpg.png; do mv $file ${file//jpg.png/jpg} ; done
```